# Question regarding the intution behind Group and Phase velocity

Tags: waves, dispersion, phase-velocity

I can't understand the proper idea behind Group and Phase Velocity.

I don't get it as clearly as I would like.

I want the intuition behind it.

Phase velocity $v_p$ is given by $\frac{ω}{k}$, This formula is brought by considering v=$υλ$,where $v$ is supposed to represent phase velocity, and we substitute

$υ$=$\frac{ω}{2π}$ ;$λ$=$\frac{2π}{k}$;

In essence we get v=$\frac{ω}{k}$ ,but why should this represent phase velocity?

Why should we make these substitution , why does it feel random?

Are these substitutions valid only for the phasal element of velocity?

Why can't I do the same and use v=$υλ$ for group velocity?

Can I get an explanation with a simple pendulum?

Answer (score 3):

This is really a comment, but plots cannot be shown in comments.

Maybe this plot will give the intuition of the difference, then the mathematics  will be clear:

[image: grwav]

> [Frequency dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) in groups of [gravity waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave) on the surface of deep water. The   red square moves with the phase velocity, and the       green circles propagate with the group velocity. In this deep-water case, the phase velocity is twice the group velocity. The red square overtakes two green circles when moving from the left to the right of the figure.
> New waves seem to emerge at the back of a wave group, grow in amplitude until they are at the center of the group, and vanish at the wave group front.
> For surface gravity waves, the water particle velocities are much smaller than the phase velocity, in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

$Sin(kx-\omega t)$ Which is an equation for a wave,

Consider t = t +1

x = x+ w/k

Aka evaluate the point on the wave, when t has moved 1 second into the future, and x has moved a distance w/k from where you evaluated it originally.

$k(x+\frac{\omega}{k})- \omega(t+1)
= kx - \omega t$

Meaning that in 1 second at a distance w/k away from some point , the field is exactly the same value, and is inphase with the same point. Doing a bit of imagination, it is clear to see that the speed of the wave is w/k  as in 1 second, that same point has moved a distance w/k,

I'm sure there are more actual mathematically sound arguments but this is the one that is most intuative.

Another one I know is that$  \frac{\omega}{k}$

is $\frac{2\pi}{T} \frac{\lambda}{2\pi}
= \lambda * (1/T)
=\lambda * F$

which is the standard formula, wavelength times frequency